# How to reduce the padding inside Shiny Input boxes?

Tags: css, r, shiny

There are a lot of questions on how to reduce/extend the padding and the margins outside Input boxes, but I can't find any on how to reduce the padding of the value/text inside and the box border itself.

For example, the standard padding seems to look like:

[image]

I'm looking to change it to:

[image]

But I can't find any relevant CSS properties to change it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this as the first argument for your `fluidPage`:

```
tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
        ".form-control { height:auto; padding:3px 5px;}"
    ))
)
```

The first padding (`3px`) refers to top and bottom, the second (`5px`) to right and left: you can modify them as you wish, e.g. to reduce them even more you can put `padding:1px 2px;` or even `0` or [whatever](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).

---

### Explanation

When you open a Shiny app in the browser, you can right-click on any element you want to modify, select Inspect, and in the developer tools check the related Styles to see where it's CSS attributes come from. I saw that the padding of my textInput boxes were styled by the `form-control` class, so that's what I needed to modify.

I think the simplest way to modify CSS in Shiny is to put the style tag in the header tag in the beginning of the page as I did above, but see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) for other options and more details about this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a CSS property for that. You can use the class `input-sm`:

```
library(shiny)

smallInput <- function(tag) {
  tag$children[[2]] <- htmltools::tagAppendAttributes(tag$children[[2]], class = "input-sm")
  tag
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  smallInput(textInput("small", "small", "")),
  textInput("normal", "normal", "")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```